# How do I install an older ethtool version on a machine?

Tags: nic

I need to test if some firmware is compatible with older ethtool versions.

The machine I am using currently have `ethtool version 5.16`, but I need to install `ethtool version 5.13`

I got the compressed file from https://mirrors.edge.kernel.org/pub/software/network/ethtool/ and have used `tar -zxvf https...` to extract the files. This extracts a directory with the contents shown below:

[image]

After reading the INSTALL file, I ran `./configure` but it gave me the following error: *configure: error: The pkg-config script could not be found or is too old.  Make sure it is in your PATH or set the PKG_CONFIG environment variable to the full path to pkg-config*

This meant that I could not run `make` or `make install` and thus am stuck.

Answer (score 0):

After speaking to colleagues, the solution was found:
`apt-get install -y pkg-config`. Thereafter the following package was also needed: `apt-get install -y libmnl-dev`

Simple installed it with `./configure`, `make` and `make install` and saw the ethtool version was as desired.